# Searching for pattern with characters and numerics in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am examining data quality and am trying to see how many rows are populated properly. The field should contain a string with one character followed by nine numerical and is of type 'Character' length 10.

Ex.

- A123456789
- B123531490
- C319861045

I have tried using PRXMATCH function, but I am unsure if i use the proper syntax. I have also tried using PROC SQL with "Where not like "[A-Z][0-9][0-9]" and so on. My feeling is that this should not be difficult to perform, does anyone have a solution?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a REGEX to make that test. Or just build the test using normal SAS functions.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  flag1 = prxmatch('/^[A-Z][0-9]{9}$/',trim(name));
  test1 = 'A' <= name <= 'Z' ;
  test2 = not notdigit(trim(substr(name,2))) ;
  test3 = length(name)=10;
  flag2 = test1 and test2 and test3 ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    name             flag1    test1    test2    test3    flag2

 1     A123456789590      0        1        1        0        0
 2     B123531490ABC      0        1        0        0        0
 3     C3198610           0        1        1        0        0
 4     A123456789         1        1        1        1        1
 5     B123531490         1        1        1        1        1
 6     C319861045         1        1        1        1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^[a-zA-z][0-9]{9}$
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

The built-in SAS functions `NOTALPHA` and `NOTDIGIT` can perform validation testing.

```
invalid_flag = notalpha(substr(s,1,1)) || notdigit(s,2) ;
```

You can select invalid records directly with a `where` statement or option

```
data invalid;
  set raw;
  where notalpha(substr(s,1,1)) || notdigit(s,2) ;  * statement;
run;

data invalid;
  set raw (where=(notalpha(substr(s,1,1)) || notdigit(s,2)));  * data set option;
run;
```

There are several functions in the `NOT*` and `ANY*` families and they can offer faster performance than the general purpose regular expression functions in the `PRX*` family.

Comment: Don't forget about the length of 10 requirement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use prxparse and prxmatch as shown below.

```
 data have;
 input name $20.;
 datalines;
 A123456789590
 B123531490ABC
 C3198610
 A123456789
B123531490
 C319861045
 ;


data want;
set have;
if _n_=1 then do; 
retain re; 
re = prxparse('/^[a-zA-z][0-9]{9}$/'); 
end;
if prxmatch(re,trim(name))  gt 0 then Flag ='Y';
else Flag ='N';
drop re;
run;
```

if you want only records those match the criteria then use

```
 data want;
set have;
if _n_=1 then do; 
retain re; 
re = prxparse('/^[a-zA-z][0-9]{9}$/'); 
end;
if prxmatch(re,trim(name));
drop re;
run;
```